# How to push checkbox values in a array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a **Treeview** application in react and I have some problem that I am not solving.

When I click **Apply** button I want to push in a array all selected values, but when I click **Cancel** button I want to remove all the last selected values.

My code is as below, please can anyone modify the code and help the for the solution?

```
export default class TreeView extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        checked: [],
        expanded: [],
        keyword:"",
        pushOn:[],
    };
}

onSearchInputChange = (event, data, searchedNodes) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        if (prevState.keyword.trim() && !data.value.trim()) {
            return {
                expanded: [],
                keyword: data.value
            };
        }
        return {
            expanded: this.getAllValuesFromNodes(searchedNodes, true),
            keyword: data.value
        };
    });
};

getHighlightText = (text, keyword) => {
    const startIndex = text.indexOf(keyword);
    return startIndex !== -1 ? (
      <span>
        {text.substring(0, startIndex)}
        <span style={{ color: "#2cb664" }}>
          {text.substring(startIndex, startIndex + keyword.length)}
        </span>
        {text.substring(startIndex + keyword.length)}
      </span>
    ) : (
        <span>{text}</span>
      );
  };

keywordFilter = (nodes, keyword) => {
    let newNodes = [];
    for (let n of nodes) {
        if(n.children) {
            const nextNodes = this.keywordFilter(n.children, keyword);
            if (nextNodes.length > 0) {
            n.children = nextNodes;
            } else if (n.label.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
            n.children = nextNodes.length > 0 ? nextNodes : [];
            }
            if (
            nextNodes.length > 0 ||
            n.label.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
            ) {
            n.label = this.getHighlightText(n.label, keyword);
            newNodes.push(n);
            }
        }else {
            if(n.label.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
                n.label = this.getHighlightText(n.label, keyword);
                newNodes.push(n);
            }
        }
    }
    return newNodes;
};

getAllValuesFromNodes = (nodes, firstLevel) => {
    if (firstLevel) {
        const values = [];
        for (let n of nodes) {
            values.push(n.value);
            if(n.children) {
                values.push(...this.getAllValuesFromNodes(n.children, false));
            }
        }
        return values;
    } else {
        const values = [];
        for (let n of nodes) {
            values.push(n.value);
            if(n.children) {
                values.push(...this.getAllValuesFromNodes(n.children, false));
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
};

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(this.state.keyword !== nextState.keyword) {
        return true;
    }
    if ( !lodash.isEqual(this.state.checked, nextState.checked)) {
        return true;
    }
    if ( !lodash.isEqual(this.state.expanded, nextState.expanded)) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

render () {
    let searchedNodes = this.state.keyword.trim()
  ? this.keywordFilter(lodash.cloneDeep(nodesData), this.state.keyword)
  : nodesData;
    return (
        <div style={{marginLeft:"30px", marginTop:"30px", width:"30%"}}>
            <div className="search">
                <Input style={{marginBottom:"10px", width:"100%"}}
                        icon="fas fa-search"
                        placeholder="Search Categories"
                        iconPosition="left"
                        onChange={(event, data) => {
                            this.onSearchInputChange(event, data, searchedNodes);
                        }}
                        className="Change"
                />
            </div>
            <hr></hr>                
            <div className="checkbox-tree">
                <CheckboxTree 
                        nodes={searchedNodes}
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        expanded={this.state.expanded}
                        onCheck={checked => this.setState({ checked })}
                        onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
                        expandOnClick
                        onClick = { () => { console.log("clicked"); }}
                        showNodeIcon={false}
                        icons={{
                            expandClose: <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i>,
                            expandOpen: <i class="fas fa-chevron-down fa-xs"></i>,
                        }}
                        nameAsArray={true}                            
                />
            </div>
            <div>
               <form class="butt">
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.cancel}>Cancel</button>
                    <button  onClick={this.pushOnArray}>Apply</button>
               </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure based on what you provided but basically you should set state property checked to this.props.checked

Comment: @Moonjist can you provide me a little example?

Comment: To provide solution to your problem I would like to know few things: 
1. What props come in from parent.
2. What do you mean by 'I want to remove all the last selected values.'

Comment: Please I will send in private the full description

Comment: Nah, describe it here if you want help

Comment: For example I check some values and I save it to the empty array, after first save I want to check some other values. After check some other values I press cancel button, If I press cancel it must uncheck values that are not saved.

Comment: @Moonjsit For example I check some values and press apply button I save it to the empty array. If I click on cancel, reverts the changes selection back to the last applied selection.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know what your project setup is but the easiest way to go with what I know is:

```
export default class TreeViewParent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: [],
  };
  onSave = (newCheckedValues) => {
    this.setState({checked: newCheckedValues})
    // perform action based on selected values here
  }
  render() {
    return <TreeView checked={this.state.checked} save={this.onSave} />
  }
}

// I am omitting parts of this component that are not related to the problem
export default class TreeView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: this.props.checked,
      expanded: [],
      keyword: "",
      pushOn:[],
    };
  }
  cancel = () => {
    this.props.save(this.props.checked)
    this.setState({checked: this.props.checked})
  }
  save = () => {this.props.save(this.state.checked)}
  render () {
    let searchedNodes = this.state.keyword.trim()
      ? this.keywordFilter(lodash.cloneDeep(nodesData), this.state.keyword)
      : nodesData;
    return (
      <div style={{marginLeft:"30px", marginTop:"30px", width:"30%"}}>
          <div className="search">
            <Input style={{marginBottom:"10px", width:"100%"}}
              icon="fas fa-search"
              placeholder="Search Categories"
              iconPosition="left"
              onChange={(event, data) => {
                this.onSearchInputChange(event, data, searchedNodes);
              }}
              className="Change"
            />
          </div>
          <hr></hr>                
          <div className="checkbox-tree">
            <CheckboxTree 
              nodes={searchedNodes}
              checked={this.state.checked}
              expanded={this.state.expanded}
              onCheck={checked => this.setState({ checked })}
              onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
              expandOnClick
              onClick = { () => { console.log("clicked"); }}
              showNodeIcon={false}
              icons={{
                expandClose: <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i>,
                expandOpen: <i class="fas fa-chevron-down fa-xs"></i>,
              }}
              nameAsArray={true}                            
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <form class="butt">
              <button type="button" onClick={this.cancel}>Cancel</button>
              <button  onClick={this.pushOnArray}>Apply</button>
           </form>
         </div>
       </div>
     )
}
```

Additionally I see you use some "advanced" stuff like cloneDeep while you do not understand basics of React. I recommend you to read the react docs, cuz answer I provided is the entry level concept of react.